# Why does TypeScript ignore the type of JSX spread props if the JSX tag is not empty?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find out if TypeScript actually type checks JSX spread attributes. I'm getting confusing results. This is my small test case ([reproduction on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCrQgDsBneAIxQBMAFHMBuAXjgBvKnDitO3AFwFMECPgA0VAL5UqmAK50MwenAAqSJgEYAFAEohIuERgaodOAB42wAG5CAdN-FcIPZQB6AD4VNUpNbRhdR0MmACYLK0pRW3tHF3cvH3Y-AODnQNc3UMplIA)):

```js
const badProps = {
  badProp: "foo",
};

function Test1() {
  return <div {...badProps} />;
}

function Test2() {
  return <div {...badProps}> </div>;
}
```

Observation:

- `Test1` is a compilation error, as I'd expect:

  ```
  Type '{ badProp: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
  ```
- `Test2` seems to ignore the type of the spread attribute though, and silently ignores the type mismatch.

On first glance I would conclude that TypeScript only type checks the spread attributes if the tag is empty, strange.

What is causing this inconsistency? Is this behavior intended?

Comment: Related [upstream issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44782).